Modifying xml generated after converting a dataframe to xml
I had a custom xml from which I captured few elements and converted it into a pandas dataframe. I again want to generate an xml from the table format. I used df.to_xml() method to get the xml. But in the xml I have additional elements like .
Please find the snippet of the xml generated.
.
Is there a way to remove such elements? Primarily the xml is storing table details such as its name, attributes and datatypes of attributes. I want the xml to be modified to the below structure.
The  should be changed to 
The  should be changed to 
And each attribute and datatype should be in a separate Sub element.
Please find the image below for ref.

I am a beginner to python and I have been spending hours in figuring it out. I was able to remove other unwanted sub elements like indexes, but I am stuck on how to change the structure and tags in the xml. Any suggestions will be of great help.
This is the code I used to convert custom xml to pandas dataframe and then again to a simple xml using to_xml(). I have also included the code to remove one other unwanted sub element index.
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse('xmlfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
entity_list = root.findall('.//Entity')
entity_names = [e.get('Name') for e in entity_list]
attribute_lists = []
attribute_dtype_lists = []
for entity in entity_list:
    attributes = [a.get('Name') for a in entity.findall('.//Attribute')]
    attribute_dtype = [d.get('DataType') for d in entity.findall('.//Attribute')]
    attribute_lists.append(attributes)
    attribute_dtype_lists.append(attribute_dtype)
df=pd.DataFrame({'Table':entity_names,'Attributes':attribute_lists,'dType':attribute_dtype_lists})
df.columns = ['Table','Attributes','DataType']
df.to_xml('data.xml')
mytree = et.parse('data.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()
for user in range(len(attribute_lists)):
    myroot[user].remove(myroot[user][0])
mytree.write('output.xml')

The initial custom xml used to generate the dataframe which is named xmlfile.xml is below.
<ESpace Key="ESpace:y7vmLUGpAMoLhw4MvpnAPg" Name="Onboarding_Core" UserProviderEspace="Users" DefaultThemeNewRuntime="ThemeReference:rQ3WUJw0o0+BC9ZDjXD7uA" DefaultTransition="Fade" UseCookies="Yes" WebScreenRenderingMode="HTML5" ModuleType="CrossDevice">
<Flows>
...
</Flows>
<Actions>
...
</Actions>
<Entities>
<Entity Key="Entity:X2oBACCeRUeSQxJFoyn1hA" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" Public="Yes" Name="Document">
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:_EXIewz0o024UgjslFt7_g" IsMandatory="Yes" Name="Id" DataType="Long Integer" IsAutoNumber="Yes"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:ypRA49SJBkexc+ICR12zdw" Length="50" Name="Name" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:mdWB6OaTkE26BwxQRRfbBg" Name="CreatedOn" DataType="Date Time"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:W0foZDFa5kme6QySnTNEMA" Name="Binary" DataType="Binary Data"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>
<Entity Key="Entity:hIb2B2qAhkuEqNqpy82Gjg" ExposeReadOnly="Yes" Identifier="Attribute:F+WBEBQ6IkO+l0rQgJDwGQ" Public="Yes" Name="Country" Folder="Folder:SErnhCWKOUKpp39VDQVVcg">
<Indexes>
<Index Key="Index:kjd4oxtEEEOlt+KMQ4GJBg" Name="Code" Unique="Yes"/>
</Indexes>
<Attributes>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:F+WBEBQ6IkO+l0rQgJDwGQ" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="36" Name="Id" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:wOpbBhZXIkqLudnaYInFdg" Description="ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="50" Name="Code" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:4ATsI1kf5kqdmuYz79XgRA" IsMandatory="Yes" Length="100" Name="Name" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:3GiXGUiTzUe+8L1VcrfAiw" Length="50" Name="CountryDialCode" DataType="Text"/>
<Attribute Key="Attribute:DvgX_IFUuEesIR8r3bZlcQ" Name="IsActive" DataType="Boolean"/>
</Attributes>
</Entity>


try to use the attribute "attr_cols" list-like which is optional List of columns to write as attributes in row element. Hierarchical columns will be flattened with underscore delimiting the different levels.

My preference is using Powershell instead of Python.  The best way of parsing XML is only extracted needed info instead of trying to delete items after they are added.  the structure of your xml is very complicated.  It is hard to determine what items are needed and not needed.  It is also complicated to have both the Name and Type of each object.  I recommend starting by using Excel and design the Data Set (multiple Data Tables), Tables, and column you want.  Then create code to give desired results.  I can easily do in Powershell if you provide the data set you want.

Share the original xml (as text), the one you converted to DF.
Share the xml you need as output (as text)
